# Rinkeby faucet not working. Please help

Tags: ether, testnets, rinkeby, test

[image]

Trying to send some test ETH to wallet but Rinkeby faucet not working. It says insufficient funds for gas * price + value. Looks like the queue is backed up for 2 days also.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this faucet for Rinkeby tesnet:

- https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby

Comment: Did you have resolve the captcha?

Comment: this only allows me to get .1 ETH. Am I able to get more from somewhere else?

Comment: Actually many Rinkeby faucet is down, you should wait a few days and try: https://rinkeby-faucet.com/, https://testnet.help/en/ethfaucet/rinkeby

Comment: Do you know why that is? Are too many people trying to use the faucets?